# Beamer with Goettingen, xelatex: white space on top of the sidebar

Tags: beamer, xetex

Sorry, a really minor, but annoying problem. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compile it with pdflatex. Open in Adobe Reader. Result: no problem. Now compile it with xelatex. Open in Adobe Reader. Result: white space on top of the sidebar.

So I have stopped using xelatex with Goettingen, but perhaps there is another solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: lualatex doesn't appear to have this problem. Curious, though - this looks like it could be a (xelatex-induced) browser artifact. PdfXchange Viewer and the TexWorks viewer both show the white space, but it *stays the same size* even at 6400% zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the same problem as reported in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/229

The following explanation of this behaviour is given in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/229#issuecomment-263112084 :

> While TeX's 'native' DVI format has certain requirements about rounding, the PDF spec does not. This means that depending upon zoom and PDF renderer there may be artefacts dues to 'out by one' issues. At the same time, the construction of beamers coloured boxes is a complex business, as there are several layers present, even if you don't see them. This increases the chances of rounding issues.